# Using javascript with Community Builder

Tags: javascript, community-builder

Hello can I use JavaScript with community builder? Are there any limitations. I cannot find information online. A link would be very useful too! Thanks.

I tried inserting javascript in the rich text area clicking on "source":

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>
```

It got erased and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

I have no documentation on this but this sounds very reasonable from security stand point .If you can add a script tag then you might steal some info from the org ,provided hacker has access to the session Id .

Even when you submit your component for component exchange it'd validated that design file has no way to accept a script tag .